# try - catch with syntax error

Tags: php, mysql

```
try {
$stmt = $db->query('SELECT title FROM never-ending-book');
while($row = $stmt->fetch()){
    echo '<div class="lev3">'.$row['title'].'</div>';
    }
}catch(PDOException $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
};
```

result:

```
SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '-ending-book' at line 1
```

Where is the syntax error and why is `never-ending-book` become `near'-ending-book`?

Comment: put tablename in backticks!

Comment: I think dashes are not allowed in sql table names. It looks like arithmetic expression otherwise.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you happen to view the [MySQL Manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/identifiers.html) it will tell you that:

> Identifiers are converted to Unicode internally. They may contain these characters:
>
> - Permitted characters in ***unquoted*** identifiers:
>
>   - ASCII: [0-9,a-z,A-Z$_] (basic Latin letters, digits 0-9, dollar, underscore)

(my bold/italics)

And because you have not quoted your column/table names with backticks then this statement (quoted above) applies.

## Solution:

Encase your table and column names in backticks, and/or rename them to remove characters not fitting the above specification.

Also give a careful read to the [MySQL Keywords and Reserved Words listing](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/keywords.html).

---

- This question does not raise any issues with PHP Try/Catch blocks.
- It may be useful to know for future reference that when MySQL states an error, to start looking at the part of the SQL query *before* the quoted string, so `near'-ending-book` means `look at the character(s) at or before '-ending-book`.

Answer (score 2):

According to [the documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/identifiers.html):

> Permitted characters in unquoted identifiers:
>
> - ASCII: [0-9,a-z,A-Z$_] (basic Latin letters, digits 0-9, dollar, underscore)
> - Extended: U+0080 .. U+FFFF

So, as the message implies, hyphens are not permitted in schema object identifiers unless the identifier is quoted:

```
SELECT title FROM `never-ending-book`
```